# How can I disable the selection / focus halo in a swiftui list when displayed on an iPad / macOS so I can customize

Tags: list, swiftui, focus, ring, halo

Like the Weather app, my list cells have an inset / rounded look that needs a custom "selected / focused" state. I can't seem to find a way to disable the default behavior.